# Working permit in Netherlands

Tags: eu, netherlands

I have a permanent residence permit and working permit in Latvia (EU member). Can I work in The Netherlands with my documents? If not, how can I get a working permit in The Netherlands?

Comment: On what grounds were you made a permanent resident? Theyt might potentially apply to the Netherlands, or they might not. (Probably not.)

Answer (score 3):

The residence permit from Latvia doesn't allow you to work in the Netherlands. Unless it is EU blue card.

You have to apply to the NL residence permit. You or your company can do it through [IND](https://ind.nl/en).